# How to get the size of gzip compressed data from HttpURLConnection

Tags: java

Im trying to fetch the length of data that I get from URLConnection.

Since Im measuring how much data the is transferred, I dont want to know the size of the uncompressed data, but the compressed one. Unfortunately InputStream automatically decompresses gzip compressed data.

I have to manually download the whole file, in case the output is chunked and I cant get the length via connection.getContentLength();

The code is here

```
try {
    connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
    connection.connect();
    int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();

    if (contentLength == -1 && connection != null) {
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        int count = 0, len;
        while ((len = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            count += len;
        }

        contentLength = count;
    }

    totalSize += contentLength;
}
```

You can see the example for this file: http://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js
When I check the header in Chrome it says Content-Length: 11181. However I am unable to get this content length by URLConnection (it returns -1) so I attempt to download the file. However, my output is 25421 bytes, which is the size of the uncompressed file.

Thank you for any kind of help.

Comment: I found out, that I cant even get the proper Content-Encoding header. Its always null...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to set the Accept-Encoding header to "gzip, deflate", to let the server know that your client accepts compressed data.

```
String url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js";
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
connection.connect();
int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
System.out.println("Content-Length: " + contentLength);
```

Without this header you're forcing the site to return plaintext data. If the data is too large, the site may return the response in chunks, and in this case the response will not have a Content-Length header.

From [developer.mozilla, Transfer-Encoding, chunked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Transfer-Encoding):

> Data is sent in a series of chunks. The Content-Length header is omitted in this case and at the beginning of each chunk you need to add the length of the current chunk in hexadecimal format, followed by '\r\n' and then the chunk itself, followed by another '\r\n'. The terminating chunk is a regular chunk, with the exception that its length is zero. It is followed by the trailer, which consists of a (possibly empty) sequence of entity header fields.

If the response is chunked, I'm afraid you'll have to read all the data to know its size. Each chunk is  preceded by a hexadecimal number that indicates the chunk size; I suppose you could use this number to calculate the total data size, but you would still have to read all the data, so there is no benefit in doing that. We can check if the response is chunked with the Transfer-Encoding header.

```
String url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js";
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
connection.connect();
String transferEncoding = connection.getHeaderField("Transfer-Encoding");
System.out.println("Transfer-Encoding: " + transferEncoding);
```

In this case, you'll have to store the raw response data in a byte array, in order to find the size of the zipped data.

```
InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int n;
while ((n = input.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    baos.write(buffer, 0, n);
}
byte[] zippedData = baos.toByteArray();
System.out.println(zippedData.length);
```

---

So, I came up with a 'hack' that may reveal the data size of a chunked response, without reading it. If we use the Range header, the server may respond with a Content-Range header. This header would contain the bytes sent and the total bytes of the content. Note that this is not a reliable method to detect the content size, it will not work if the server doesn't support range requests.

```
String url = "https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js";        
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url)).openConnection();
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
connection.setRequestProperty("Range", "bytes=0-1");
connection.connect();

int contentLength = connection.getContentLength();
String contentRange = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Range");
if (contentRange != null) {
    contentLength = Integer.parseInt(contentRange.split("/")[1]);
}
System.out.println("Content-Length: " + contentLength);
```

Comment: I thought, that HttpURLConnection sets "Accept-Encoding" by default to gzip. You are right with the chunked Transfer-Encoding. All urls that return lenght -1 are chunked data responses. But how do i get the compressed content-length. Should i avoid using GZIPInputStream at all and decompress it manually after receiving?

Comment: If the response is chunked, I'm afraid you can't know the total size until you read all the chunks.

Comment: Apparently `HttpURLConnection` may not use a Accept-Encoding header by default (tested with eclipse, jre1.8.0), so make sure to set this header if you're expecting a zipped response. I've updated my answer with a method that may detect the total data size of a chunked response, but you should always prefer to use the Content-Length header, if it's available.

Comment: I have solved my issue by first writing the response to a ByteArrayOutputStream (baos). Now i can get the length with baos.size(). Later I check if the resource is gzip compressed and extract it with the GZIPInputStream.

Comment: Perfect! I included the Content-Range method because I thought it was interesting, but yes, the proper way is to read all the data.